# Как получить все сообщения через вк апи?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Вк api дает получить за один запрос максимум 200 сообщений. А как получить все переписки? Использую module python vk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать метод [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute)
Там можно делать до 25-ти обращениям к API за раз

Вот значение аргумента code:

```
var i = 0;
var response = API.messages.get({"count":200})["items"];
while (i != 24){
i =i + 1;
response.push(API.messages.get({"count": 200, "offset":i*200})["items"]);
}
return response;
```

Comment: Ну получим 5000 сообщений через execute, а больше-то как?)

Comment: @andreymal , почему 5000?
Создаём ещё один такой же запрос и опять шлём.
Если мне не изменяет память, то таких запросов в секунду можно минимум 2 раза отправить, а это ого-го

Comment: Вот это всё во всех подробностях и должно быть написано в ответе)

Comment: @MrMorgan Да, можно пример такого execute запроса?